# Hackable scheme implementation with decent C++ FFI

Tags: c++, scheme, ffi

I have tried: scheme48, chicken, gambit, clojure.

I am looking for a scheme implementation that's readable (the implementation itself), and has a decent C++ ffi, and good debugging suport (so when I get an exception, I should get popped into a recursive repl).

What suggestions do people have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MzScheme.](http://www.plt-scheme.org/software/mzscheme/) It can be embedded in C/C++ programs. It can be extended with C libraries, with no special interfacing code. Checkout "[Inside PLT MZScheme](http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/103p1/html/insidemz/)" for detailed documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[s7 scheme](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/snd/snd/s7.html) has worked well for me. It is in a single .c file and has a nice foreign function interface.